# Typescript : How do I declare type of prototype Object on constructor Function

Tags: typescript

I get this compile error:

property 'prototype' does not exist on value of type 'Base'

on the following class, how can I get typescript to recognise the prototype object as a type of native Object from a constructor Function?

```
interface IBase {
  extend: any;
  prototype : any;
}

declare var Base : IBase;

class Base implements IBase {

  constructor() {}

  public extend( mixins : any ) : void {
    _.extend( this.prototype, mixins );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`this.prototype` is probably not what you mean, since instances of `Base` don't have a `prototype` property (see yourself at runtime). `Base`, however, does:

```
interface IBase {
  extend: any;
}

class Base implements IBase {
  constructor() {}

  public extend( mixins : any ) : void {
    _.extend(Base.prototype, mixins );
  }
}
```

Of course, at this point, `extend` might as well be static, since it applies to all `Base` instances. Did you mean this instead?

```
  public extend( mixins : any ) : void {
    _.extend(this, mixins);
  }
```